# java.lang.IllegalStateException on connecting Android device with Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I recently tried connecting my android phone with android studio to test run my app. Howvever, when the app runs following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

The app works fine on the AVD.
Min SDK 16
Target SDK 23

My android device has Android Version 4.2.2

I want to use the theme and style that I have created and not this default theme.

Can anyone help????

Comment: post your `styles.xml`

Comment: @Vaibhav Agarwal see my answer below.

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are extending your `Activity` from `AppCompatActivity`, you must use theme descendant from `Theme.AppCompat`.

Thus you should define your theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- All customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

And use it like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```